# Haskell greater than or equal

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to convert a list of integers into a list of characters to resemble grades. Here is my code in Haskell:

```
grade :: [int] -> [char]

grade array = if 90 <= head array then ['A'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 80 <= head array then ['B'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 70 <= head array then ['C'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 60 <= head array then ['D'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 60 > head array then ['F'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else [] array
```

The compiler GHCi gives me this error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘[int] -> [char]’
            with actual type ‘[t0]’
Relevant bindings include
  array :: [int] (bound at grade.hs:3:7)
  grade :: [int] -> [char] (bound at grade.hs:3:1)
The function ‘[]’ is applied to one argument,
but its type ‘[t0]’ has none
In the expression: [] array
In the expression:
  if 60 > head array then ['F'] ++ grade (tail array) else [] array
```

I'm not sure what '[t0]' means

thanks in advance

I changed my code to this:

```
grade :: [Int] -> [Char]

grade array = if 90 <= head array then ['A'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 80 <= head array then ['B'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 70 <= head array then ['C'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 60 <= head array then ['D'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 60 > head array then ['F'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else [] = array
```

thanks for your recommendations, but now it is giving me a parse error at '='? I'm not sure what is wrong now

Comment: Do you mean ``else [] ++ array`` (which would be the same as just ``else array``)? ``[] array`` is parsed as function application, and ``[]`` is not a function.

Comment: Did you mean `Int` and `Char` instead of `int` and `char` respectively?

Comment: Could you explain in words what the last line is supposed to do?

Comment: when the tail of the list has no more  values, i wanted the recursion to stop, so i tried to make the last list in the recursion equal to nothing

Comment: @Stephanie: Do you know about `map`? If you do, write `gradeSingle :: Int -> Char` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The preferable way to achieve what you want is to use pattern matching:

```
grade [] = []
grade array = if 90 <= head array then ['A'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 80 <= head array then ['B'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 70 <= head array then ['C'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else if 60 <= head array then ['D'] ++ grade(tail array)
          else ['F'] ++ grade(tail array)
```

Also, you can use pattern matching to get rid of repeating `head`/`tail` calls:

```
grade [] = []
grade (x:xs) = if 90 <= x then ['A'] ++ grade xs
          else if 80 <= x then ['B'] ++ grade xs
          else if 70 <= x then ['C'] ++ grade xs
          else if 60 <= x then ['D'] ++ grade xs 
          else ['F'] ++ grade(xs)
```

Edit: to haskellize even more, you can use guards:

```
grade [] = []
grade (x:xs)
    | 90 <= x   = ['A'] ++ grade xs
    | 80 <= x   = ['B'] ++ grade xs
    | 70 <= x   = ['C'] ++ grade xs
    | 60 <= x   = ['D'] ++ grade xs
    | otherwise = ['F'] ++ grade xs
```

Edit #2: removed parentheses next to `grade`, per @rampion's comment.